# `Exception: Range not found` in function to get a users email and the date on edit of specific column's rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a google scripts app that picks up on a gsheets users email whilst they fill in a value into a row of a cell (promotion cell) in A and writes the email to the email cell (B) then the date they filled it in into the Date cell (C).

| Promotion Cell | Email | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | johndoe@gmail | 2022-10-10 |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |

The idea is that using the onEdit I can get a users email and the date automatically in rows B and C. But for some reason, my code is not working the error being on the range variable in the `fillEmailAndDate` function. I am not sure why this is not executing.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.info(e)
  // get the active sheet
  sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()

  // Get the active cell
  var cell = e.source.getActiveCell();

  // Get the row and column of the active cell
  var row = cell.getRow(); //1.0 clicking on cell 1 of promotion cell
  var col = cell.getColumn(); // 1.0
  // Get the letter of the promotion column
  var promotionColumn = 'C';

  // Get the letters of the email and date columns
  var emailColumn = 'E';
  var dateColumn = 'F';

  // If the active cell is in the promotion column
  if (Math.round(col) == getNumber(promotionColumn)) {

    // Run the fillEmailAndDate function
    fillEmailAndDate(e, coverage_sheet, promotionColumn, emailColumn, dateColumn, row);
  }
}

function fillEmailAndDate(e, sheet, promotionColumn, emailColumn, dateColumn, lastRow) {
  // Get the range of cells to be checked
  var range = sheet.getRange(promotionColumn + "2:" + promotionColumn + lastRow);

  // Use the onEdit trigger to detect when a cell in the promotion column is edited
  sheet.getRange(range).setOnEdit(function(e) {
    // Get the active cell
    var cell = e.source.getActiveCell();

    // Get the row and column of the active cell
    var row = cell.getRow();
    var col = cell.getColumn();

    // If the active cell is in the promotion column
    if (col == promotionColumn) {
      // Get the email and date columns for the active row
      var emailCell = sheet.getRange(emailColumn + row);
      var dateCell = sheet.getRange(dateColumn + row);

      // Get the user's email address from the email column
      var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

      // Fill in the email and date cells with the user's email address and the current date
      emailCell.setValue(email);
      dateCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  });
}
function getNumber(letter) {
  // Make sure letter is uppercase
  letter = letter.toUpperCase();
  // Convert letter to a character code and return the corresponding number
  return letter.charCodeAt(0) - 64;
}
```

Comment: About `But for some reason, my code is not working the error being on the range variable in the fillEmailAndDate function. I am not sure why this is not executing.`, in your script of `fillEmailAndDate`, there is no method of `setOnEdit` in Class Range. I think that this might be the reason for your issue. And, about `var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`, I think that in the current stage, the shared user's email cannot be returned, while the owner's email can be retrieved.

Comment: And also, in your `fillEmailAndDate`, Class Range object of `var range = sheet.getRange(promotionColumn + "2:" + promotionColumn + lastRow);` is used with `sheet.getRange(range)`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue of `Exception: Range not found`.

Comment: Also where is `coverage_sheet` defined?

Comment: Which is the error line?